# Typescript `if(x in obj)` does not narrow my custom Record

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I checked if a string exists in my custom record but `if(x in obj)` gaurd is not working.
This is my sample code and it has error:

```js
type Answer = 'yes' | 'no';
type ToDo = Partial<Record<Answer, string>>;

function doFunction(toDo: ToDo, hisAnswer: string): string {
  if (hisAnswer in toDo) {
    return toDo[hisAnswer];
    // ^--- Error!
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
    // 'string' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Record<Answer, string>>'.
    // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string'
    //  was found on type 'Partial<Record<Answer, string>>'.ts(7053)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is `hisAnswer` a `string` instead of an `Answer`?

Comment: This is just an example. In real code this value comes from another interface that I cannot change

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript cannot *guarantee* that the result is a string. Conforming to a type does not mean there are no excess properties, consider the following code:

```typescript
const toDo = {
   yes: "hello",
   no : "world",
   foo: 42
};

const result = doFunction(toDo, "foo");

console.log(typeof result); //number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgZwO4QE5QLxQOQgg7KAHxzgHtsBuAKFEigBUyARMzKABQENVgBLLgBsAPACUIAYzKoAJsPjI0AGigJgqPnADmAPh01qAMwCucCfzJwoMsgDFT5vpYAUwFmQBcjdyoAWfBAUUVC81DW0ASlD1TS0oAG9qKCg+Qyhnf0DEYJSrN1YIhKTkqFQIYGNUPPcAbUygtABdGmSAX2p26ilEYCh8tixEkrwELwAiXwhBQTIxpWKocihxpGlBGTmFwzJPKAAWACYOg261UvxjQV6sG3szCzhXHygx7dmIk8sEMkEIADoZlpXOAIGQ0mUEJdgB8oAB6WFwYwAWwARmggA) (fails compilation but can be run to see the result)

The variable `toDo` *conforms* to the `ToDo` type because it has `yes` and `no` keys. It also has a `foo` key where the value is not a string. This is why TypeScript does not guarantee what the result is - according to the type, it is going to be a string. However, the compiler does not have absolute knowledge of what actual value would be passed in. The variable `toDo` might even be constructed at runtime, thus completely out of scope for compile-time analysis.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. But the problem is not return the type. Error says `'string' can't be used to index type`. Maybe some type of guard is needed.

Comment: @rostamiani  You see in the example that it *might* produce a result that's not `undefined` but since at compile-time there is no information what would happen, TS decides to implicitly use `any`. The error message states that *the reason* for the `any` is the lack of foreknowledge what indexing by an arbitrary string would result in.

Comment: And yes, you can make a type guard to ensure that `hisAnswer` is indeed an `Answer` type. Then there would be no ambiguity.